# How does the example find the lib in Oozie best case?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie

According to the document of Oozie, I try to run a map-reduce example on Oozie. As everyone knows, 'workflow.xml' (and 'coordinator.xml') should be in HDFS.

Then input the command: `oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run`. And I also know the 'job.properties' should be in local file system.

But there are two things confused me:

1.why dose the jar or class variable in workflow.xml come from directory Lib of HDFS?

2.There is a picture showing the content of oozie-examples-4.3.1.jar. This jar is in HDFS, how can it import Lib?
[image]

Forgive my poor English.

Comment: I don't understand your question but you should read the Oozie Cookbooks here http://hadooped.blogspot.com/2013/06/apache-oozie-part-1-workflow-with-hdfs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighted red box is part of the Hadoop and Java default classpath. Any Java code that's ran within YARN, as part of MapReduce has access to the packages that appear when you run `hadoop classpath` command. By the way, `mapred.*` classes of Hadoop are almost all deprecated

That's nothing to do with Oozie, per say, but Oozie extends the Hadoop classpath with the [Oozie ShareLib](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/), which must be explicitly enabled with a property file argument

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
```

And in addition to that classpath,, Oozie will send the `${wf.application.path}/lib` directory to all running jobs

Comment: I still don't know how dose the example jar find the lib? You know, if you package your project by maven, all of libraries are packaged into the jar. Then, it should find the class which is referenced in you own class. But the example jar is so simple so that I can't find any other package in it.

Comment: Of course, I do understand what you mean in this answer. Maybe I should think the hadoop lib of example project as the jdk lib of one pure java project. We never reference the class or package of jdk. But our projects are still good running as long as we config the jdk environment in java calsspath.  Maybe I should read some source code of hadoop and oozie. Or is there any article or blog you can offer me , which can make me really understand this question?

Comment: Only if you use the shade plugin will your JAR have its dependencies. You should never include the Hadoop mapreduce dependencies as part of your JAR because the cluster already has those JARs after you installed Hadoop on it. Oozie isn't any different, it has its own JAR files (including the example JAR). All you're asking about is a standard Java `CLASSPATH` environment variable, nothing specific to Hadoop other than what classes are imported